# Crosssite Scripting issues

Tags: php, xss

Right now im trying to filter all of my variables to secure my site from xss.
I read a few things here and there and to me it seems the best way to do that would be to whitelist all charackters that i need
for numbers i use

```
$adrnr = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $adrnr);
```

but if it comes to words Im haveing a issue since im german I would need to whitelist ü,ä,ö and ß is there a way to do so?

Comment: preg_replace("/[^0-9]*/", "", $adrnr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can (or even should) filter/convert/validate your input, XSS prevention has to be done for your output, because what you have to do is context-based. `htmlspecialchars()` saves you in a lot of locations in your output, but not in all. See the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

For your input validation of german names you may simply use this:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ ]+$/', $nachname)
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with preg_replace?

Comment: @Chaos: I wrote about validation. So i used the whitelist method with the goal to show an error to the user. preg_replace is a blacklist method and thus only suitable for (automatic) conversion/canonization. It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: ye  took me a while to get how this works but this seems to solve my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape HTML chars.

Comment: im testing my code with netsparker and
if i filter it like this $vorname = htmlspecialchars($vorname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); it still tells me that there is a threat

Comment: There is not any security threat with htmlspecialchars, try inserting some html, you'll see.